# How to traverse char pointer to count the number of types a particular character is there

Tags: c, string, pointers

For example if I have a normal string and I am looking for the number of `a` in the string I would do the following:

```
char string[] = "HelloThere";
int lengthOfString = strlen(string);
int count = 0;

for(int i=0;i<lengthOfString;i++){
    if(string[i] == 'e'){
        count++;
    }

}
```

But now I have a char pointer and I am not sure how to do it correctly. This is what I have done, but it is producing an error.

```
char *string;        <------------ Contains "HelloThere"
int lengthOfString = strlen(string);
int count = 0;

for(int i=0;i<lengthOfString;i++){
        if(*string[i] == 'e'){      <-------- I have a feeling this line of mine is wrong.
            count++;
}
```

Can someone show me how to do this the correct way?

**EDIT:** Another quick question: What if I had an array of string pointer and I wanted to iterate through one of those string pointers to look for `e`. What would be the correct syntax to do that?

```
char *string[10];        <------------ Contains "HelloThere"
string[0] = strtok(someBiggerString,"=");
int lengthOfString = strlen(string[0]);
int count = 0;

for(int i=0;i<lengthOfString;i++){
        if(string[i] == 'e'){      <-----------  
            count++;
}
```

The syntax in the arrowed line above wont work now since it will think I am referring to another string pointer. What would I do in this case if I wanted to iterate through that string char by char?

Comment: you do not need to dereference a `string[i]` call, so remove the * in the line you marked as wrong.

Comment: @JohannesWalcher but will this traverse the string? What I mean is string[0] will be the first char in the string?

Comment: `*string[i] == 'e'` --> `*string++ == 'e'` or `string[i] == 'e'`

Comment: If you look at just the posted code `string` is an uninitialized pointer. If we are to assume that `string` is a valid pointer, you can fix your problem by using `if(string[i] == 'e')` instead of `if(*string[i] == 'e')`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if its a `char*` you need to make sure the array of characters it is pointing at is eliminated by a `\0` character to make `strlen()` work..

Considering that it is eliminated by `\0` and that `lengthOfString` contains the proper length, all you need is to dereference the pointer..

The statement `string[i]` is internally changed to `*(string+i)`. So you do not need an extra `*`.

```
for(int i = 0;i < lengthOfString;i++){
        if(string[i] == 'e'){      
            count++;
}
```

The above changed code is good enough to get you going.

---

**EDIT**

Its a little difficult to understand what you are trying to say but if I am not wrong, your code suggests that the string to be searched is pointed by the pointer stored at `string[0]`. Since you used `strlen()` on that only.

In that case you can access using

```
for(int i = 0;i < lengthOfString;i++){
        if(*(string[0]+i) == 'e'){      
            count++;
}
```

Or

```
for(int i = 0;i < lengthOfString;i++){
        if(string[0][i] == 'e'){      
            count++;
}
```

Comment: I got the value into the string pointer by using strtok to break up a bigger string. So for example : string = strtok(biggerString,"="); . Does this mean it is still terminated with the '\0' and strlen would work?

Comment: @Billy, Yes. As the man page of `strtok` says. *Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token.*

Comment: Thank you. I have one last quick question about a similar doubt I have. I have edited my question. Could you please take a look and see if you know what to do in that situation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right in where your error exists, it should instead be:

`if (string[i] == 'e'`

`*string` refers to the first element of the array `string` that is `string[0]`

The statement `*string[i] == 'e'` instead will result in an error

In response to your edit:

You now have an array of `char*` so if you may access the characters in a `char*` by using `string[0]`, to access each character of an array of char pointers you would need `string[i][j]` for example to step through each character as you would with a two-dimensional array since an array of char pointers may be looked at as `char**` or `char [][]`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have one more doubt relating to this issue. I have updated my question and added the doubt, could you take a look at the edit and see if you can answer my doubt?

Comment: @Billy Note that the string "HelloThere" would only be stored in the first string of `*string[10]` which would be `string[0]`.